# How to change array variable after filter - Angular Ui Pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angular-ui

I have this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPEejM). I need to change the value of **`'totalItems'`** after the filter. I'm trying to do it like this inside the filter:

```
scope.totalItems = scope.filteredlist.length;
```

But the value doesn't changes. I read that I should do something like this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Z9lAvogqSAbVNJ6eQ89) (calling the filter again inside my controller), but I don't know how to adapt it to my code.

PS: For test the filter, try to type something in the search box, like **`'o'`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the result of the filtered array in a variable using the syntax `item in items | filter:x as results`

> `variable in expression as alias_expression` – You can also provide an optional ?>alias expression which will then store the intermediate results of the repeater >after the filters have been applied. Typically this is used to render a special >message when a filter is active on the repeater, but the filtered result set is >empty.
>
> For example: `item in items | filter:x as results` will store the fragment of the >repeated items as results, but only after the items have been processed through >the filter.

Then you can use `{{results.length}}` to get the length of the filtered results.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

---

After looking at your pen in more detail, you can get the totalItems value in your scope by just making a one-line change in your code.  In your pagination filter, you are doing

```
scope.totalItems = scope.filteredlist.length;
```

But the length that you want is actually of the `input` so if you change it to this, then `totalItems` will have the value that you expect

```
scope.totalItems = input.length;
```

I don't like that solution as much since you end up sorta polluting some other scope within the pagination filter but it gives you your answer. (I just would need more time that I have right now to come up with a "cleaner" solution)

Comment: Ok, good. But i need to access the variable `results` inside my controller. It is possible?

Comment: Yes you can access the variable `results` in your controller.  I tried it, but it exposed some other issues.  See my update to the answer for how you can get your `totalItems` variable working.

Comment: Thanks for your attention to my question, but `scope.totalItems = input.length;` is not what I want, because initially i need `scope.totalItems = scope.filteredlist.length;` Maybe you can see directly my code in the pen.

Comment: Does something like this pen work for you? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmVYLv?editors=101

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you very much for your time. I'm going to review the code, if i have any question about it, i'll post it.